# "Internar error 500" ¿Fallo del servidor o de la programación?

Tags: servidor

Tengo código funcionando en un servidor Linux v50-49. El caso es que al usar algunos botones con acceso a la base de datos aparece este error:

[image: internal error]

La empresa que lo desarrolló dice que es el servidor que no funciona pero yo creo que es un fallo de programación.

¿Hay base suficiente como para desmentir que sea el servidor que está fallando?

Comment: Si tienes los logs, ahi debe venir que ocasiona ese error.

Comment: Si te han dado esa respuesta sin mirar los logs, probablemente sea culpa de esa empresa.

Comment: si dices que servicio es te podemos dar pista de donde pueden estar los logs, generalmente esta en `/var/log/` si es apache `/var/log/apache/error.log` puedes hacer un `tail -f /var/log/apache/error.log` acceder a la web y ver el error en vivo

Comment: Voy a mirar los logs ahora que sé dónde encontrarlos. La verdad es que no tengo mucha idea del tipo de servicio pero lo voy a mirar.

Answer (score 0):

> **500 - Internal Server Error**
>
> Es un código comúnmente emitido por aplicaciones empotradas en
> servidores web, mismas que generan contenido dinámicamente, por
> ejemplo aplicaciones montadas en IIS o Tomcat, cuando se encuentran
> con situaciones de error **ajenas a la naturaleza del servidor web**.

---

Al indicar que solo ocurre cuando las funcionalidades relacionadas a los botones trata de acceder a la base de datos, se podría deducir que hay un error en la aplicación y podría deberse quizás a que no logra conectarse a la base de datos o que hay un error de programación dentro de dichas funcionalidades.

---

**Referencia:**

- [Anexo:Códigos de estado HTTP](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:C%C3%B3digos_de_estado_HTTP)
- [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.5.1)